# Problemas de permisos a la hora de solicitar un Submit Data Request

Tags: permisos, submit

Estoy intentando hacer una solicitud de data request a través de la API Data Connect y la respuesta de la API es siempre la misma:

```
{

    "detail": "Invalid user access level for the specified project/account",    
    "status": 403,    
    "type": "error",    
    "title": "Forbidden",    
    "id": 42941325,    
    "errors": [    
        {  "detail": "Invalid user access level for the specified project/account",    
            "title": "Forbidden",    
            "type": "error"    
        }    
    ]    
}
```

Hicimos la prueba con el mismo usuario en la plataforma y nos deja acceder y bajar el documento. Sin embargo, a través de la API nos dice que no tenemos permisos.

EL body que estamos pasando en la solicitud es este:

```
{    
    "description": "My Week Extract",    
    "scheduleInterval": "WEEK",    
    "reoccuringInterval": 1,    
    "effectiveFrom": "2023-04-21T14:19:00Z",    
    "effectiveTo": "2024-04-21T16:00:00Z",    
    "serviceGroups": "all",    
    "projectId": "d85a1df9-1818-470c-ae51-1675e6007d9c" 
}
```

¿Alguién nos puede ayudar?
Muchas gracias